# L5.5 Create symlink between storage and public directories on shared hosting using SSH

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, server

I've setup my production server on a shared hosting my directory structure looks like this (my project is placed at same level as public):

```
/home/user/my-laravel-project/
/home/user/public_html
```

This is how I'm storing my data in `Storage > Public Disc`

```
$data->store('path/to/data', 'public');
```

On production, using SSH, when I run this command `php artisan storage:link`.
It creates a symlink between `storage/app/public` and `my-laravel-project/public`
I want this link to be created between `storage/app/public` and `/home/user/public_html`

**What I've tried**

- Tried removing `my-laravel-project/public` then tried `php artisan
  storage:link` .. it failed with an error `No file or directory`
- I tried changing storage path from `storage_path('app/public)` to
  `public_path()` under `config/filesystem.php` but no success
- I've also tried to create symlink using shell command `ln -nsf
  /home/user/my-laravel-project/storage/app/public
  /home/user/public_html` but no success

Tried many other little tweaks but nothing works for me .. I'm looking for a proper solution to create a symlink between `storage/app/public` and `/home/user/public_html` on my shared server

**Note** I don't want to change paths in `config/filesystems.php` as that's not a proper solution

My current server is setup on Siteground with php version 7.0.32 and Laravel 5.5.43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create defaults symlinks you should create one for yourself.

This is the symlink pattern:

```
ln -s target source
```

So in your case you have to do following:

```
ln -s /home/user/public_html storage/app/public
```

Comment: nothing happened .. I am still stuck at this problem .. can't seem to find any proper solution.. any further help would be really appreciated

Comment: when I ran that command ... terminal showed up nothing .. it just to new line waiting for new command

Comment: can you check wether a sym folder was created? If not can you run the command with sudo `

Comment: I am on a shared host .. just checked the public_html folder ... there isn't any new directory created ... is there any better way to check if link was successful?

Comment: Hmm there should be a "folder" if its created you can run following comand to check it `ls -la` something like your/path -> to/path should appear if that appears it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `php artisan storage:link` on SSH terminal.
It will create a symbolic file(storage) on public folder and move it to the public_html/

Comment: I tried this method worked fine on namecheap hosting

Answer (score 0):

This answer from Sudaraka Senevirathne works on siteground.

Simply run `php artisan storage:link` on SSH terminal. It will create a symbolic file (storage) on a public folder and move it to the public_html/.